# How to use local typings for plain JS files in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a plain JS module (vendored) that exports a function:

In `./vendor/my-lib.js`:

```
export function doStuff(mandatoryArgumentX, optionalArgumentY) {
}
```

I also have typings for it - in `./vendor/my-lib-typings.d.ts`.

```
export function doStuff(mandatoryArgumentX: number, optionalArgumentY?: string)
```

Now, I have a TypeScript module that wants to use it:

```
import {doStuff} from '../vendor/my-lib';
doStuff(44);
```

How do I get my TypeScript module to use the typing when dealing with this import? Global modules (imported with `import 'my-lib'`) are easy, because I can just put the same module name in typings. It's not the case here though, since the paths are really dynamic.

Is there anything I can put in any of these 3 files that will solve this puzzle (besides rewriting JS to TS)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same name between the .d.ts file and the .js file it should work - so just rename the .d.ts file and you should be good.

Comment: In this case only the d.ts gets processed. tsc compiles, but the build output does not include the .js.

Comment: Are you using the new TypeScript 1.8 `--allowJs` switch with `--out`?  If not, TypeScript will not emit or copy JS files so you'll have to copy the JS file to your output location as a separate step.

Comment: I do use `--allowJs` but not `--out` (which is now deprecated in favor of `--outFile`, but anyway I don't use either). According to docs `--outFile` is all about concatenation and single-file output, I wonder if it can break anything for me.

Comment: OK perhaps this is a feature that should be added to TS.  I think for now your best bet is to copy the JS file in a build step.